# InstallShield FilesInUse

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield

I'm using InstallShield AdminStudio 2014 (integrated in VS, but I can edit stand-alone too) and I want to close an application if it's open before installing.  I have found the Custom Action KillProcess, and that works, however, it's a non-UI immediate kill of the processes no questions asked.  I see the built in FilesInUse Dialog that most of us have seen before when running an install warning us to close the listed applications before continuing with a RETRY button once you've closed them.  The problem is, I can't seem to find any documentation or posts online, even in the Users Guide and sample installs on how to populate the list; and what other, if any, actions are required after that.  I was able to put the dialog in the UI sequence but when I select retry it immediately ends the install, ignore continues.  So I know I'm missing some pieces to it.  At a minimum how do I populate the list of files.  I know some things are not entirely obvious like KillProcess requires you to populate a semi-colon delimited property called ISTermiateProcesses and not a property of the Custom Action.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.  I've reached out to known IS users and they didn't know how to use this feature either, many searches later, I'm posting here.  This is the last step holding up a project ready for QA.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: The FilesInUse dialog is a Windows Installer thing, and Windows will populate it with the processes it can discover that are using files that will be replaced. In general you don't need to populate it. Older versions of Windows are not as good at detecting the processes using files that are to be replaced. It's not obvious why you want to kill the process if Windows hasn't found that it impacts your install, unless you have an older OS version.

Comment: I'm updating config files for the application which can't use my installed pieces until the application restarts. The application is Firefox and the install adds certifacte exceptions for our webapp which they just selected to install. Without the close and restart continuing through to the next pages will not work. Chrome and IE do not need to restart to continue, but if they're using FF they do. Your answer explains a lot though.

Comment: I'll mark as answered if you can post as an answer.  I didn't realize the dialog was self-populating based on what is in memory and components in the install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FilesInUse dialog is a Windows Installer thing, and Windows will populate it with the processes it can discover that are using files that will be replaced. In general you don't need to populate it. Older versions of Windows are not as good at detecting the processes using files that are to be replaced. It's not obvious why you want to kill the process if Windows hasn't found that it impacts your install, unless you have an older OS version.